# Maven plugin compatibility error with newest version of Java

Tags: java, maven, homebrew, jenv

So recently I was given a maven project I need to compile, but there seems to be some compatibility issues with wr04j and the most recent version of Java I have installed on my Mac.

```
Execution {redacted} of goal ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-maven-plugin:1.8.0:run failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-maven-plugin:1.8.0:run: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
```

Upon further research I found a Java version manager similar to `nvm` with node.  I followed all of the steps I could find to download prior versions of Java hoping to find the one that worked.  One issue arrived that caskroom and homebrew don't appear to host versions of Java older than Java11.

Is there something I am missing?  I run these lines in my command line

`brew tap caskroom/versions`

`brew search java`

The only versions that show up after doing this are

```
java
java-beta
java11
java6
```

All of the instructions list versions 6-11 as available.  Maybe they were removed? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?  Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can recommend [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/), it works on MAC, and is a bit more specific than homebrew, and has many different versions of Java available.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I'll have to check that out.

Comment: Have you run your build with `--errors` to show the full exception?

Comment: It had to do with the plugin not being compatible with the newest version of Java.  My options were to either use a compatible version of Java or use the solution below.  I chose the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was unable to find a version of Java before 11 on homebrew other than Java6, but found this fix for anyone receiving the same error.

`<plugin>` section for wr04j in the `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: it works, although, an explanation why this would work would be appreciated.

Comment: It's been awhile, but if I remember correctly it was a version compatibility issue.